# Water and Uniform Electic Field

Tags: electromagnetism

I was wondering if water molecules align to a uniform electric field, since water is an electric dipole. And if so what are the consequences of that?

Comment: Consider the nature of atomic behavior in a fluid. Can you reasonably assume a constant orientation for any particular molecule? How does that affect your expectation for this kind of question?

Comment: I assume you mean the relatively big velocity of water molecules? That makes sense! So the effect of the field is not noticeable?

Comment: The field has an effect, but it has to compete with the randomizing effect of on-going collisions. See CR Drost's answer.

Answer (score 1):

They do align on average, but it's not an "all at once" type thing: they are all jiggling about a bit and only on average do you see that the dipoles point more and more in the direction of the field as the field gets stronger and stronger. The main consequence is that, as a result, light moves slower in water than it does in vacuum, which creates the reflections and refractions of light at water surfaces. That's not properly speaking a "uniform" electric field, but it is the most common way you'll see the response of water to electric fields.

Comment: Would the fact that there are mobile $\rm H_3O^+$ abd $\rm OH^-$ ions rather than just water molecules also have an effect?

Comment: Possibly the question is about a steady uniform uniform electric field when the dielectric constant of water (and ice) is about 80?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they do align, making water what is called a "dielectric" material, a material that when one applies an electric field on them, the aligning of the dipoles in the material create an opposing electric field, making the net $\vec{E}$ smaller than the applied $\vec{E}$. This happens also to materials with molecules that don't have a dipole moment, the electrons in the atoms are a bit moved because of the $E$ field creating a little dipole which opposes the electric field.

Sorry for the English, I hope it helped!